# reload jtable with paging

Tags: javascript, jquery-jtable

I want to reload JTable with the number of the page where I am there.

I have this code to reload JTable `$("#JTable").jtable('load');`

But this code will reload the whole table and will bring me to the first page. How to reload JTable with the page number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply by write "reload" instead of "load". The code will be like this:

```
$("#JTable").jtable('reload');
```